# Multiline label in UIStackView with UIScrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, uistoryboard, uistackview

in my storyboard I have two horizontal stackview embedded in a vertical stackview. The second stackview include a multiline label. [image]

The result is this and I don't understand how I can fix the problem.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want actually?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
want to output like these?

```
Using stackview1 please take switch horizontal proirity 251 , 751
stackview2 - alightment center , disturbution proptionaly
```